# Why do the timestamp of files change when copied to Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, nautilus, timestamp

I have to make files (documents, images) backup from my **phone to PC** frequently. Then I copy those backup files back to my phone.

When I do it in **Windows**, the timestamps of the files remain intact. For example, if an image was taken on `25-Feb-2023` it would remain the same after copying *back to phone* which is important for me to preserve the *date taken*.

But, when done in **Ubuntu**, all of the timestamps get overwritten by the time I *copied back* the files. For example, if I copy the same image from the example above, the date would get changed to `21-Sep-2023` (the date I've copied the file).

How can I solve this issue?

NB.

1. I am using **Nautilus** for copying files.
2. I have activated `noatime` to optimize SSD performance.

Comment: How is the phone mounted? MTP? Or is the SD card directly attached to the PC using a card reader and then mounted as an exFAT or other filesystem? Finally: does it matter? If these pics are taken on a phone, the EXIF data will contain the actual date on which they were taken, wouldn't it?

Comment: What phone is it? The file names of pictures in my Android phone contain the date and time, and the time-stamp is also preserved, when I import via MTP and USB. But as muru suggests, you should be able to use the EXIF data, if nothing else is preserved. You can install the program (package) `exif`.

Comment: @sudodus The Phone is running on Android 13. Google photos sort all the photos by the file's date, I don't know why. Thus I lose all the date information for the photos.

Comment: @muru The phone is mounted via USB MTP. When photos are transferred back to phone, Google photos list all photos by the modified date. Thus I lose all the date data for my photos.

Comment: Is the problem (only) when the files are transferred back to the phone? Is that when the creation date is changed? Is the date preserved when the files are transferred from the phone to the computer?

Comment: Would it be an option to use a micro SD card for the file transfer (to move the card between the devices)?